# active link wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I'm working on a wordpress site for a client.
I have the navigation working and when they hover over the navigations, they will get a green background. This is true for each link-navigation item.

I also want the selected page have that same background, so the visitor of the site, knows where he currently is.

What I have so far:

Wordpress:

```
<div id="nav">  
   <?php wp_nav_menu ( array ('theme_location' => 'header-nav','container' => false)); ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    /*float:right;*/
    float:left;
    height:6em;
    /*width:560px;*/
    /*width:612px;*/
    width:710px;
    /*background:#525252;*/
}

#nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li a{
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
}
#nav li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:left;
    padding:3.4em 0.4em 0 0;
    position:relative;
    right:-1em;
    /*left:6em;*/
    color:#fff;
    height:2.1em;
}
#nav li a:hover{
    color:#333;
    /*background:#60b5b2;*/
    background:#69dc37;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav li a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background:#69dc37;
}
```

I was searching the internet and found [a post about menu highlighting](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting). I tried that, but it didn't worked.

I need some advice/help on this to get the active-link (background) working.

Comment: `:active` is not what you're thinking it means. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:active. Basically active is the style if you click and hold on a link. Remember IE5/6 when links flashed red? The red activated via `:active`. You need to somehow capture the url, compare it to the menu links and add a new class to it

Comment: @Ryan. That's what i've tried to do with the link added in my first post. This didn't worked, i think because of wp_nav_menu ??

Answer (score 0):

Please correct background to background-color in your CSS code:

```
#nav li a:hover{
    color:#333;
    /*background:#60b5b2;*/
    background-color:#69dc37;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#nav li a:active {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#69dc37;
}
```